# How to override subtheme settings (inheritance)?

Tags: theming

I am having some difficulty overwriting my subtheme code using my own theme.css file (located in sites>all>themes). I can find the code that results in the display of whichever css style property I'm trying to change (e.g., font-family in the header region) easily, using the chrome DevTool, but when I go to target that area in my own css file it seems not to have any effect on the display. Is there any general methodology with which I can go about inheriting my adjustments to the theme styles? FYI I have renamed my subtheme's files so that is not the issue.

Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've cleared the cache and all that before trying to inspect any changes, it sounds like your base theme (the theme you've based your sub-theme on) is one of those themes where the configuration is for a large part done by means of the administrative interface. This means that edits done to the `.css files`have no effect, as they're overridden by settings the administrative interface.

A number of popular themes has this property, including the *Adaptive Themes* family and *Omega 3*.

To check out if this is the case, navigate to *Administration » Appearance » Settings* for your theme (or sub-theme).  If there is a *lot* of settings for fonts, etc., hacking the `.css` files will not help much and you need to use the administrative interface for styling.